# Regroup 3 test plan into 1 test

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen, hp-performance-center

I use HP Performance Center & I've 3 tests plan that I want to regroup into a forth.
I've Map-Prod1, Map-Prod2 & Map-Prod3 with several scripts & I want a new test plan with ALL script that are in these 3 test plan.

I didn't find a solution, except recreate a new one & reselect ALL my scripts.
There is reallay no solution to do that without recreate one ?

Thanks.
Yacine

Comment: Create a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've to create a new one...